# When will I get the following exception from Activemq "error(condition:amqp:resource-limit-exceeded,description:local-idle-timeout expired)"

Tags: activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I am using Activemq to send and receive events between services. everything works fine but some times later I am getting the following error from Activemq

```
error(condition:amqp:resource-limit-exceeded,description:local-idle-timeout expired)
```

I dont know whenand why this error is coming from the broker. Am I missing any configurations? or How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Without further details it is difficult to know but the error would seem to indicate that your client is not honoring the idle timeout that the broker has indicated it requires you to fulfill by sending empty frames if no other activity is present in the wire from your client.